# Fill missing values by centering the rows means to zero

Tags: python, missing-data, pandas

I have have a dataframe with students grades. I want to fill the NA's values. For that I'm gonna change the mean of each student to zero.

```
grades = pd.DataFrame({'test1': [np.nan, 60, 80], 'test2': [60, 60, 85], 'test3': [70, np.nan, 85], 'test4': [80, 80, 100]}, index = ['Matt', 'Sam', 'Tom'])

      test1  test2  test3  test4
Matt    NaN     60   70.0     80
Sam    60.0     60    NaN     80
Tom    80.0     85   85.0    100
```

vec is the mean of each student

```
vec = grades.mean(axis = 1)
```

I subtract then divide each grade by vec

```
grades = grades.sub(vec, axis = 0)
grades = grades.div(vec, axis = 'rows')
```

I fill the missing value by the mean/test

```
grades = grades.fillna(grades.mean(axis = 0))

grades = grades.multiply(vec, axis = 'rows')
grades = grades.add(vec, axis = 0)
```

Finally my dataframe looks like this :

```
      test1  test2      test3  test4
Matt   63.5   60.0  70.000000   80.0
Sam    60.0   60.0  65.714286   80.0
Tom    80.0   85.0  85.000000  100.0
```

Do you think it is a right way to fill missing values ? Is that statistically correct ?